# AngularJS nested directive priority with ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a case where I have a child and parent directive. I need to run a function on the parent once all the child directives have been processed. I would expect to be able to do this in the parents postlink function. However, as the child directives use ngRepeat this is not happening. What happens is the parent pre and post link fire followed by each child pre and post link function. I established that this was down to ngRepeat using a priority of 1000.

How do I make the parent postlink function run after all child directives have executed?

I've created a plnkr of the problem here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/rYK1ZjoWdukXEWFTri19?p=preview

```js
(function(){
  'use strict';
  
  angular.module('plunker', ['ngSanitize']);
  
  angular
    .module('plunker')
    .controller('MainCtrl', function() {});
  
  angular
    .module('plunker')
    .directive('parentItem', function($log) {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          controller: controller,
          link: {
            pre: parentPrelink,
            post: parentPostlink
          }
      };
  }).directive('childItem', function($log) {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          require: '^parentItem',
          controllerAs: 'vm',
          template: '<h4 ng-transclude="title" id="$id"></h4><div ng-transclude="detail"></div>',       
          transclude: {
            title: 'childTitle',
            detail: '?childDetail'
          },          
          link: {
            pre: childPrelink,
            post: childPostlink
          }
      };
  });
  
  function controller($scope, $compile, $window, $timeout, $log){
    var ctrl = this;
    
      ctrl.log = '';
      
      ctrl.logger = function(msg){
        $log.info(msg);
        ctrl.log += ('<li>' + msg + '</li>'); 
      }
  }
  
  function childPrelink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller){
    controller.logger('child pre');
  }
  function childPostlink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller){
    controller.logger('child post');
  }
  function parentPrelink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller){
    controller.logger('parent pre');
  }
  function parentPostlink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller, transcludeFn){
    controller.logger('parent post');
  }
    
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="sanitize@*" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    
    <parent-item>
    
      <child-item ng-repeat="n in [1, 2, 3, 4] track by $index">
        <child-title>Child {{n}} title</child-title>
        <child-detail>Child {{n}} detail</child-detail>
      </child-item>

    </parent-item> 
  
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: priority matters only when two directives are on same element, and not in case of parent child, though not totally sure